# How to confirm whether Wordpress website has been compromised?

Tags: php, wordpress

I had created a Wordpress website www.saftech.ae sometime back (end Jan- strt Feb). The website was working alright till I had last checked on 10th March 2014. A few days back I was informed by my colleague that the site is not opening. On going on the website I was greeted with a URL blocked by the service provider stating the material on the site comes under the Restricted Content Categories.

I tried opening my wordpress account but got the same page of URL being blocked. I couldn't even access the cpanel directly and I had to open it via the IP address. Being a first timer at making a website, I don't know what to look for in such a situation. I opened the files via an FTP client and on opening the .htacess file , I found the following code in it,

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

What does this mean? Is my website compromised? How do I confirm? What should I do incase the website is compromised?
I have already shot a mail to my service provider and called the support team innumerable times but have not gotten any help from their end till now. Kindly help.

**So, I requested the third party host where my website is being hosted to run a scan and I was told that my site had been compromised due to a phishing attack which may have been caused by one of the themes. I removed all those files, added more security plugins but now my site has been blacklisted on PhishTank and McAfee. I have already send them a request to review the website again. What else can I do to unblock my website?**

Comment: `.htaccess` code is for pretty URLs in WordPress. This file can be created automatically by WordPress when you are modifiying permalinks configurations. Does this file has correct user rights ie : 644?

Comment: The link works for me... (http://saftech.ae). A little slow at first, but works.

Comment: The link (saftech.ae) works for me too. Please clear your browser history, cache and cookies and re-try

Comment: I also confirm that the link (saftech.ae) works for me too, slowly, but the page loads without problem, also I have looked at the source HTML code - nothing unusual inside...

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie Yes the file has correct user rights

Comment: @ZameerKhan still blocked after clearing all the above. Etisalat is my service provider, could it be something from their side??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My website is finally unblocked and working perfectly. This mess had started from the twentytwelve theme which was already present in wordpress when I had started using it. The twentytwelve theme was vulnerable in my case which led to the whole phishing site being hosted on my domain. 
All I did was remove the whole twentytwelve theme folder, sent review requests to Phishtank and McAfee where my website had been blacklisted to unblock it and constantly kept bugging my ISP to unblock the website. It took almost 10 days for my site to come back online.

Also,I added Sucuri and Wordfence security plugins with email alerts for any kind of changes or logins.

PS: I would advice people to just keep the theme they are using and remove all the other inactive ones. I am using the responsive theme and today I had to remove twentythirteen theme as the file was modified but not by me.

Answer (score 0):

I too have the same problem with my wordpress site. It works every where except certain fire walls would block it. In my case McAfee blocks it on certain IP addresses. I don't think what you describe means that your site is compromised, it is just that your firewall categorizes some of the scripts in your site as belonging to a malicious category. If you have lately Installed any new theme or any new plugin, Try getting rid of that and it should work.

Moreover I am also getting blocked to visit your site due to McAfee settings.

Comment: I got a call from my ISP in reply to my complaint to them regarding my  blocked website and they also said the same thing that they detected a phishing site piggy backing my website, so they had blocked it. Now that the bad files have been removed, they said they would unblock it. But yea my website has been blacklisted on McAfee and PhishTank